# Play video where it left from after terminate the application

Tags: ios, swift, video, video-streaming, avfoundation

Is the following possible for iOS:

A playing video is terminated in the midst of being watched by a user and then when they reopen the application (later on), the video will be played from where they left off?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build logic into your app so that:

- you store the video name and current position when the user moves away from the app: use the AVPlayer Current time: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1390404-currenttime
- when the app is opened again, you check if there is a current video being watched and if so you seek to the time you stored above: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385953-seek